# export dataset to drive colab

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I have this code in my machine export 
two fils train.tfrecord and eval.tfrecord. 
But when i upload it to Colab dosn't export any things

## Write the dataset

> ```
> train_writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.train_output_path)
> eval_writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.eval_output_path)
>
> process_dataset(
>     train_writer=train_writer,
>     eval_writer=eval_writer,
>     data_dir=FLAGS.data_dir)
>
> train_writer.close() eval_writer.close()
> ```
>
> full code here Github:
>   https://github.com/frankgu/3d-DenseNet/blob/sagemaker/prepare_data_main.py

Colaboratory [NoteBook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u9Rf9l6Sp9GZEpgmVAa8v29ZcbGrVf9d)

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u9Rf9l6Sp9GZEpgmVAa8v29ZcbGrVf9d

Comment: What files are you uploading to Colab? Can you share a notebook that shows what you did and the problem you observed?

Comment: This is my notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u9Rf9l6Sp9GZEpgmVAa8v29ZcbGrVf9d

Comment: It looks like you interrupted the execution of the last cell. What's the actual problem you are trying to address?

Comment: I have Solved the problem files are saved a left panel in of colab